# Get tags for post_type

Tags: tags

I have several custom post types that all share the same tags.

On the archive for each custom post type I want to display a list of tags used, and the number of posts associated with each. `get_tags()` by default pulls all its information from the entire site content.

I can't find any filters for the `get_tags()` function, and I don't want to perform and intensive queries/functions to manually count and restrict.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/category.php#L257), there's a filter called, appropriately, `get_tags`. Unfortunately, the docs are a little thin. Hopefully this can get you started, though.

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
global $wpdb;

// set the target relationship here
$post_type = 'post';
$taxonomy = 'tag';

$terms_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT
    tt.term_id
FROM
    {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr,
    {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt,
    {$wpdb->posts} p
WHERE 1=1
    AND tr.object_id = p.id
    AND p.post_type = '%s'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    AND tt.taxonomy ='%s'
", $post_type, $taxonomy ) );

// here you are
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
'include' => $terms_ids,
'orderby' => 'name',
'order' => 'ASC'
) );
```

It will get your tag terms for a specific custom post type. Then you can do:

```
foreach( $terms as $tag ) {
    echo '<li class="type-tag">' . $tag->name . '</li>'; 
}
```

to show your tags on a list.

Comment: If you add some information to this answer explaining what it does, and why it solves the problem, you'll get an upvote from me. Code alone does not make for a valuable answer...

Comment: @t31os - Done it.

Comment: Sorry but unfortunately that does not clarify the answer sufficiently enough for me. *For example:* Why are you calling WPDB's `get_col` and is it required and if so, why...